# How can I extract the last field in a string?

Tags: bash

How can I extract the last field in a string? I have a string:

```
xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1
```

I want to extract the last part of the string, that is `VGA1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rev` and `cut` if the string has delimiters, as in your case:

```
var="xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1"
rev <<< "$var" | cut -f1 -d' ' | rev
# output => VGA1
```

- the first `rev` reverses the string so that the last token shifts to the beginning, though in reverse
- `cut -f1` extracts the first field, using space as the delimiter
- the second `rev` reverses the extracted field to its original state

**The good thing about this solution is that it doesn't depend upon how many fields precede the last token.**

---

Related post: [How to find the last field using 'cut'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727107/how-to-find-the-last-field-using-cut-linux)

Answer (score 1):

If this string always contains the same number of spaces, we can consider each space-separated part as a field and use `cut` to extract it :

```
$ echo "xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1" | cut -d' ' -f7
VGA1
```

If that's not the case, we can use regex to match from the end, for example with `grep` :

```
$ echo "xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1" | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
VGA1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with Bash builtins only (no external commands) :

```
var="xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1"
[[ "$var" =~ [[:space:]]([^[:space:]]+)([[:space:]]*)$ ]]
match="${BASH_REMATCH[1]-}"
```

Please note the regular expression used will tolerate trailing whitespace in the string ; it could be simplified to avoid that if it is considered a bug rather than a feature :

```
[[ "$var" =~ [[:space:]]([^[:space:]]+)$ ]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach:

```
echo "xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1" | \
sed 's/ /\
/g' | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use awk:

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' <<< 'xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1'
VGA1
```

`NF` is the number of fields in the record, and `$NF` prints the field with number `NF`, i.e., the last one. Fields are by default blank separated.

Alternatively, using shell parameter expansion:

```
$ str='xres = 0: +*VGA1 1600/423x900/238+0+0  VGA1'
$ echo "${str##* }"
VGA1
```

This removes the longest matching string from the beginning, where the pattern to match is `*` : "anything, followed by a space".