# How to get last part of string in substring by variable number of delimiters

Tags: shell, ksh

I am struggeling a bit.
As I write a ksh script I need to extract a Substring of a String where the number of  occurances of the dilimiter is flexible.

This is, as my String holds the name of a file which might be compressed several times, therefore having more than 1 point (.). 
These points would be my delimiter, but as the supplier might include version numbers into the name of the file (e.g. software-v.3.2.4.tar.gz), I find no was to cut off the last suffix.

The progress is as follows:

Filename is saved in variable. 
File is decompressed first time. (taking the .gz suffix away of the file)
Now I need to extract the .tar archive. But my command would still be holding the .gz suffix. Command would not work as the file has the suffix no more.

How do I get the suffix of my variable. 
I can not guarantee that the numbers of delimiters stay the same.

I tried several combinations of | rev | cur -d'.' | rev, but in this case I only get the suffix.

I aswell tried initialize the $fileName variable again with the actual name of the file, but therefore I would need to search the whole directory. I try to avoid that.

...

```
fileName="whole file name"
pathTo="path in which it should be moved after decompression"

if [ "$fileType" = "gz" ]; then

    gzip $pathTo$fileName -d $pathTo

    #Problem occurs right here

    tar xfv $pathTo$fileName -C $pathTo

else 
    echo "Unknown Filetype. Cannot decompress. Script stopped."
    exit

fi
```

...

I am thankful for any help.
Greets

Yonkske

Comment: please provide some examples of what you have and what you want

Comment: see Charles Duffy's answer to a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22727262/7366100 - don't forget to check out that BashFAQ link, too

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `| rev | cut -d'.' -f 1 | rev` but use `| rev | cut -d'.' -f 2- | rev`

Answer (score 0):

Variable Substitution is the best choose here, as it is a shell built in it also the fastest.

```
filename='software-v.3.2.4.tar.gz'
echo ${filename##*.}
```

Output will be `gz`

This will not modify the value of the variable $filename.

`if [[ "${filename##*.}" == "gz" ]]; then`

How it work,

`${var#pattern}` - Use value of var after removing text that match pattern from the left

`${var##pattern}` - Same as above but remove the longest matching piece instead the shortest

`${var%pattern}` - Use value of var after removing text that match pattern from the right

`${var%%pattern}` - Same as above but remove the longest matching piece instead the shortest

There is more but this is the relevant ones here.

The Limitation of this they cannot be Nested.