# Bash - Extract region from AWS arn

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, grep

Very simple task: extract the region from an AWS arn.

Example:

```
arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:12345678912:layer:my-awsome-layer:3
```

I need to extract `eu-west-2`

I have a working regex for this: [`^(?:[^:]+:){3}([^:]+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/Apyhb8/1)

I tried this command, but it returns the entire string:

```
echo "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:12345678912:layer:my-awsome-layer:3" | grep -oP '^(?:[^:]+:){3}([^:]+).*'
```

output: `arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:12345678912:layer:my-awsome-layer:3`

What is wrong with the above?

Comment: Why not just a `cut -d':' -f4`? Why do you need regex at all?

Comment: Your value is in capture group 1.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I sort of realised that by looking at the output on regex101, but I still would not know how to get that out :D

Comment: There is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex

Comment: You can refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727107/how-to-find-the-last-field-using-cut

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Inian for the quick and good answer in the comments:

```
echo "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:12345678912:layer:my-awsome-layer:3" | cut -d':' -f4
```

Does the trick.

output: `eu-west-2`

Answer (score 2):

A more flexible approach:

```
grep -oP '\w{2}-\w+-\d+'
```

Answer (score 2):

You get back the whole line because you are using `.*` at the end of the pattern.

As you are using grep `-oP` you can make use of `\K` to forget what is matched so far:

```
grep -oP '^(?:[^:]+:){3}\K[^:]+'
```

An alternative using `awk` setting `:` as the field separator and printing the fourth field:

```
awk -F: '{print $4}'
```

Or using `sed` and replace with capture group 2, as capture group 1 is repeated 3 times:

```
sed 's/^\([^:]\+:\)\{3\}\([^:]\+\).*/\2/'
```

The examples will output:

```
eu-west-2
```