# Convert multiline string to array

Tags: arrays, bash, newline

I have this script:

```
nmapout=`sudo nmap -sP 10.0.0.0/24`
names=`echo "$nmapout" | grep "MAC" | grep -o '(.\+)'`
echo "$names"
```

now the `$names` variable contains strings delimited with newlines:

```
>_
 (Netgear)
 (Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.)
 (Apple)
```

I tried to do the array conversion with the sub-string approach:

```
names=(${names//\\n/ })
echo "${names[@]}"
```

But the problem is that I can't access them by indexing (i.e., `${names[$i]` etc.), if I run this loop

```
for (( i=0; i<${#names[@]}; i++ ))
do
     echo "$i: ${names[$i]"
     # do some processing with ${names[$i]}
done
```

I get this output:

```
>_
 0: (Netgear)
 1: (Hon
 2: Hai
```

but what I want is:

```
>_
 0: (Netgear)
 1: (Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.)
 2: (Apple)
```

I could not figure out a good way to do this, please note that the second string has spaces in it.

Comment: Any reason why do you want array? I would prefer to use `read` by line loop.

Comment: @kan , actually this is a small portion of a large script, the original script uses the index for other purposes, that's why I want to keep the array.

Comment: Related: how to convert a _space-delimited_ string to a bash array: [Reading a delimited string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293887/4561887)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Set `IFS` (Internal Field Separator). Shell uses the `IFS` variable to determine what the field separators are. By default, `IFS` is set to the *space character*. Change it to the *newline* character, as demonstrated below:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
names="Netgear
Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.
Apple"
    
SAVEIFS=$IFS   # Save current IFS (Internal Field Separator)
IFS=$'\n'      # Change IFS to newline char
names=($names) # split the `names` string into an array by the same name
IFS=$SAVEIFS   # Restore original IFS

for (( i=0; i<${#names[@]}; i++ ))
do
    echo "$i: ${names[$i]}"
done
```

Output

```
0: Netgear
1: Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.
2: Apple
```

Comment: Because there could be special characters in the original `$IFS`, it's better to avoid trying to store it. Better to just wrap the whole thing in a subshell with parentheses.

Comment: @etheranger , I am new in bash scripting, could you please elaborate more on "subshell with parantheses"?

Comment: @ramgorur [This manual](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) explains all the detail. I'm suggesting it here to make use of the variable scope mentioned on that page. Basically if you put a command or commands in (parentheses), they act a bit like a new instance of bash. They inherit variables and settings from the running script, but usually don't propagate changes back.

Comment: If i execute that as non-root, I get `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: you can change IFS just for one line using IFS=$'\n' names=(${names}) on line 9. It's the same as joining line 8 and line 9.

Comment: @koppor For me, that error was because I had `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash`. `my_arr=(...)` is bash-specific array initialization. I bet that your root account worked because it used bash as the default shell.

Comment: If you initialize an array with an unquoted variable, then the variable value is not only subject to word splitting, but also to pathname expansion. So, for example, in `x='foo *'; arr=($x)` the array contains `foo` and all filenames of the current working directory.

Comment: Actually @andres I could be wrong, but for me, in GNU bash, version 4.4.19, that IFS assignment changes the IFS for the rest of the script and not just 1 line. The IFS did however only affect one line when I did this:  `IFS=$'\n' read -ra names <<< "$names"`

Comment: It's probably worth noting in your answer that `IFS` = **Internal Field Separator**. Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184863/what-is-the-meaning-of-ifs-n-in-bash-scripting/184867#184867

Comment: A more common `for` loop line would look like this: `for name in ${names_array[@]}; do` ... `done`.

Comment: note if you're using zsh (all new mac versions) you have to do `setopt sh_word_split` to enable splitting

Comment: What does the dollar sign (`$`) do in `IFS=$'\n'`? Where is this documented?

Comment: @GabrielStaples `man bash` section QUOTING: "Words of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard."

Answer (score 44):

Bash also has a `readarray` builtin command, easily searchable in the man page.  It uses newline (`\n`) as the default delimiter, and `MAPFILE` as the default array, so one can do just like so:

```sh
    names="Netgear
    Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.
    Apple"

    readarray -t <<<$names

    printf "0: ${MAPFILE[0]}\n1: ${MAPFILE[1]}\n2: ${MAPFILE[2]}\n"
```

The `-t` option removes the delimiter (`'\n'`), so that it can be explicitly added in `printf`.  The output is:

```
    0: Netgear
    1: Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.
    2: Apple
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question that was asked. `readarray` is designed to do exactly this

Comment: This indeed is the correct answer to the specific question.

Comment: `readarray` was introduced in bash v4.0. Some systems like macOS <11.* are still on bash v3.2. In that case `IFS`-based solutions can used instead.

Answer (score 26):

Let me contribute to [Sanket Parmar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628076/bash-convert-n-delimited-strings-into-array#answer-24628676). If you can extract string splitting and processing into a separate function, there is no need to save and restore `$IFS` — use `local` instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

function print_with_line_numbers {
    local IFS=$'\n'
    local lines=($1)
    local i
    for (( i=0; i<${#lines[@]}; i++ )) ; do
        echo "$i: ${lines[$i]}"
    done
}

names="Netgear
Hon Hai Precision Ind. Co.
Apple"

print_with_line_numbers "$names"
```

See also:

- [Setting IFS for a single statement](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92187/setting-ifs-for-a-single-statement)

Answer (score 8):

### How to read a multi-line string into a regular bash "indexed" array

The Bash [`shellcheck`](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) static code analyzer and checker tool recommends [in SC2206](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206) to use `read -r` or `mapfile`. Their `mapfile` example is complete, but their `read` example only covers the case of splitting a string by spaces, not newlines, so I learned the complete form of the `read` command for this purpose from [@Toni Dietze's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628076/convert-multiline-string-to-array/71575442#comment99872268_56130798).

So, here is how to use both to split a string by newlines. Note that `<<<` is called a *"herestring"*. It is similar to `<<` which is a *"heredoc"*, and `<` which reads in a file:

```bash
# split the multiline string stored in variable `var` by newlines, and
# store it into array `myarray`

# Option 1
# - this technique will KEEP empty lines as elements in the array!
# ie: you may end up with some elements being **empty strings**!
mapfile -t myarray <<< "$multiline_string"

# OR: Option 2 [my preference]
# - this technique will NOT keep empty lines as elements in the array!
# ie: you will NOT end up with any elements which are empty strings!
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a myarray <<< "$multiline_string"
```

There is also a 3rd technique I use the most, which is not necessarily recommended by *shellcheck*, but which is fine if you use it correctly, and which is *far more readable* than either of the options above. I use it in many scripts in my [`eRCaGuy_dotfiles/useful_scripts` directory here](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/tree/master/useful_scripts). Clone that repo and run `grep -rn "IFS"` in it to find all places where I use that technique.

See here for where I first learned this: [Answer here by @Sanket Parmar: Convert multiline string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628676/4561887).

Here it is:

```bash
# Option 3 [not necessarily recommended by shellcheck perhaps, since you must
# NOT use quotes around the right-hand variable, but it is **much
# easier to read**, and one I very commonly use!]
#
# Convert any multi-line string to an "indexed array" of elements:
#
# See:
# 1. "eRCaGuy_dotfiles/useful_scripts/find_and_replace.sh" for an example 
#    of this.
# 1. *****where I first learned it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628676/4561887
SAVEIFS=$IFS   # Save current IFS (Internal Field Separator).
IFS=$'\n'      # Change IFS (Internal Field Separator) to the newline char.
# Split a long string into a bash "indexed array" (via the parenthesis),
# separating by IFS (newline chars); notice that you must intentionally NOT use
# quotes around the parenthesis and variable here for this to work!
myarray=($multiline_string) 
IFS=$SAVEIFS   # Restore IFS
```

### See also:

1. Where I learned my "Option 3" above: [Answer here by @Sanket Parmar: Convert multiline string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24628676/4561887)
2. [Read file into array with empty lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31843590/4561887)
3. An example where I read a bash multi-line string into a bash array using the `read` cmd: [Find all files in a directory that are not directories themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070772/4561887)

Answer (score 7):

As others said, IFS will help you.`IFS=$'\n' read -ra array <<< "$names"`
if your variable has string with spaces, put it between double quotes.
Now you can easily take all values in a array by `${array[@]}`

Comment: By default, `read` uses `\n` as delimiter, so you have to put `-d ''` in the `read` command, otherwise the array only contains the first line of `$names`. Corrected version: `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array <<< "$names"`. You also forgot to put a `$` in front the `{`.

Comment: I am new to this, Could you elaborate more about `-r` and `-a` usage in this command

Comment: I am a bit confused. You already use `-r` and `-a` in your initial answer, just shortened to `-ra`. In my comment, I added `-d ''`. The bash man page nicely explains all these command line options (look for the `read` builtin command).

Comment: @ToniDietze, thanks for your corrections! I never would have figured out to add `-d ''` otherwise, and that part is essential. I added it [to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575442/4561887).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the `read` builtin will return a non-zero exit status upon encountering an EOF, so if you have set `-e` somewhere in your shell script as the [_Bash Strict Mode_](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/) document suggests, you better mask the exit code of `read`, e. g.: `read -ra array -d '' <<< "${names}" || true`.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Adding the **needed** `null byte` delimiter in @HariBharathi answer</sup>

```sh
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a array <<< "$names"
```

**Remark:** Unlike `mapfile`/`readarray`, this one is compatible with macOS bash 3.2