# Read file into array with empty lines

Tags: arrays, bash

I'm using this code to load file into array in bash:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a LINES < "$PAR1"
```

But unfortunately this code skips empty lines.

I tried the next code:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -r -a LINES < "$PAR1"
```

But this variant only loads one line.

How do I load file to array in bash, without skipping empty lines?

P.S. I check the number of loaded lines by the next command:

```
echo ${#LINES[@]}
```

Comment: All-caps variable names are reserved by convention to avoid overwriting system-impacting names by mistake. See fourth paragraph of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, keeping in mind that environment variables and shell variables share a namespace.

Comment: See also: [Convert multiline string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24628076/4561887). I've just updated [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575442/4561887) to highlight this important distinction between `read` and `mapfile`: `read` does _not_ keep empty elements in the array, but `mapfile` _does_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid doing anything fancy, and stay compatible with all versions of bash in common use (as of this writing, Apple is shipping bash 3.2.x to avoid needing to comply with the GPLv3):

```
lines=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  lines+=( "$line" )
done
```

See also [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Great thanks! As for the last line I used the code from your link:
`lines=( )
while IFS= read -r line 
do
  lines+=( "$line" )
done < "$PAR1"
[[ -n $line ]] && lines+=( "$line" )`

Comment: Correct- the more complete answer (to fix skipping the last line) is to add `[[ -n $line ]] && lines+=( "$line" )` at the end. Learned this the hard way!

Comment: @skupjoe, or you can make it `while IFS= read -r line || [[ $line ]]; do`. You only need that if you use files made by someone who runs Windows (or tools that follow Microsoft's lead in considering newlines line _separators_ instead of _terminators_), though, so if you're a right-thinking person who uses UNIX and only uses files made by people who do likewise, it's completely unnecessary, right? :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmm, well, creating and using such a file that is only one entry long which is in LF format and doesn't end with a newline in VSCode (yes, from Windows machine) seems to exhibit this behavior when I then use this file in a Bash script that loads it to an array, executed from OSX, synced via Dropbox. Complicated, I know, but I dev cross-platform and from many different clients :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`mapfile`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/mapfile) available in BASH 4+

```
mapfile -t lines < "$PAR1"
```