# string concatenation from a bash array

Tags: arrays, string, bash, loops, concatenation

I'm having so much troubles trying to create a string that is the result of the concatenation of an array with a bit of addition every time it goes through the loop

```
# HERE IS THE VALUE OF CHANGELOG.JSON
# [
#   13,
#   14,
#   22
# ]

readarray -t lines <<<"$(cat $1/changelog.json | jq '.[]')"

echo "check if my array is filled"
echo ${lines[0]}
echo ${lines[1]}
echo ${lines[2]}
echo "my array is correctly filled.."

for i in ${!lines[@]}
do
    var2="$var2 | jq '.[$((($i+1)))]=${lines[$i]}'"
    echo "my var2 during loop: $var2"
done

echo "my var2 after loop $var2"
```

For some reasons, this script give me this as output

```
$ /bin/bash add-changelog.sh Blupods-front-v3/
check if my array is filled
13
14
22
my array is correctly filled..
'y var2 during loop:  | jq '.[1]=13
' | jq '.[2]=14loop:  | jq '.[1]=13
' | jq '.[3]=22'oop:  | jq '.[1]=13
' | jq '.[3]=22'op  | jq '.[1]=13
```

do you guys have any idea of how may i make it work ? i've already went through a lot of the solutions on stackoverflow and none of them worked (using += for concatenation) I've heard on other questions this is due to the fact that for/while loop create a subshell but even in the loop the variable doesn't get memorized.. also I don't have any pipe except for the read array at first.

EDIT: Here I add my expected result, maybe it will help you guys help me
I am not trying to execute this command right away, i'm just trying to concat a string in a for loop the expected result should be this

```
echo $var2
| jq '.[1]=13' | jq '.[2]=14 | jq '.[3]=22'
```

Comment: What is `var2="$var2 | jq '.[$((($i+1)))]=${lines[$i]}'"` supposed to do?  What is the initial value of var2?  That assignment would not execute the pipeline if that is what you are expecting.  It will simply assign the whole string to var2, and not the result of the pipeline execution.  You need `$(...)` to execute the pipeline.

Comment: I do not want to execute it right away, i want to concatenate that string and only execute it outside of the loop at the end (the ultimate goal of this is to update a json file)

there is no initial value to var2

Comment: Please see the edit to see what i am trying to achieve

Comment: What do you want to *do* with `$var2`? There is likely a solution that doesn't require dynamically generating a pipeline of multiple calls to `jq`.

Comment: Something like `jq --slurpfile cl changelog.json '.[:3] = $cl[]' original.json` may do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the values in the array have `\r` characters. You can remove them with `tr -d '\r'`.
Actually I suggest to write like this:

```
lines=($(jq '.[]' < "$1"/changelog.json | tr -d '\r'))
```

And although your for-loop is correct, it can be improved too:

```
var2=
for i in ${!lines[@]}; do
    var2="$var2 | jq '.[$((i+1))]=${lines[i]}'"
done
```

Comment: this is not doing anything because there is nothing inside "lines"

Comment: I managed to make it work by doing this instead
`lines=($(cat "$1"/changelog.json | jq '.[]' | tr -d '\r'))`
the solution you provided at first created a segmentation fault inside jq
if you edit your answer i will approve it, Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Rakiah how about `lines=($(jq '.[]' < "$1"/changelog.json | tr -d '\r'))` ? This should be equivalent, but without a useless `cat` ;-)

Comment: Yes, the second solution without the cat work just like the cat one, but there is still a problem, if my changelog.json file has an array of string containing spaces, the lines array contains much more key than one per value, for some reason the lines array also split everytime it encounter a space, do you have a solution for this aswell ? Thank you anyways

Comment: well a quick search find an answer for me
if there is anyone with the same problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628076/bash-convert-n-delimited-strings-into-array
this worked, and everything is fine now, Thank you janos

Answer (score 0):

This might help instead if the respective line in the for loop.

```
var2="$(echo "$var2" | jq '.[$((($i+1)))]=${lines[$i]}')"
```

Comment: I am not trying to execute this command right away, i'm just trying to concat a string in a for loop the expected result should be this
please see my edit for what I want to achieve

Comment: @Rakiah: Sorry, I now see what you were aiming for, thanks for your edit. I did some testing and figured, that `-t` for `readarray` didn't have the desired effects for me. In your case, this might case these strange line breaks in your output. However, variable substitution got me further. Could you try using `${lines[$i]//$'\n'/}` in the body of your `for` loop instead of just `${lines[$i]}`?

Comment: Thank you for your time,
using this line
`var2="$var2 | jq '.[$((($i+1)))]=${lines[$i]//$'\n'/}'"`
I get this output 
`'y var2 during loop:  | jq '.[1]=17
' | jq '.[2]=13 '.[1]=17
' | jq '.[3]=14'.[1]=17`

Comment: but i do believe that readarray -t is the problem though, because with a normal array created like this `array=(13 17 22)` this give an output that look like much more what i want

Comment: @Rakiah: That looks better! Can you do `var2=""` before the loop?

Comment: @Rakiah: I agree, there is something wrong with `readarray -t` and the compulsory newline provided by `${lines[$i]}`. This thread leads towards a workaround it seems. (Btw: Need to go now, back in a bit.)

Comment: You think so ? i don't even know that's so strange now i get this
`' | jq '.[3]=17'op  | jq '.[1]=13`
and the thing is, i'm only echoing once at the end, like this
`echo "my var2 after loop $var2"`
where does the "op" come from and why there is no "my var2 after loop"
that's really out of my understanding lol