# Storing String Output of SED Commnd in an Array In Shell Script

Tags: arrays, xml, shell, sed

I have an XML file of the format:

```
<classes>

 <subject lb="Fall Sem 2020">
  <name>Operating System</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Theory</type>
  <faculty>Prof. XYZ</faculty> 
 </subject>

 <subject lb="Spring Sem 2020">
  <name>Web Development</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Lab</type>
 </subject>

 <subject lb="Fall Sem 2021">
  <name>Computer Network</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Theory</type>
  <faculty>Prof. ABC</faculty> 
 </subject>

 <subject lb="Spring Sem 2021">
  <name>Software Engineering</name>
  <credit>3</credit>
  <type>Lab</type>
 </subject>

</classes>
```

I'm able to get the desired result using `sed` command. i.e. `sed -En 's/.* lb="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file`

Output:

```
Fall Sem 2020
Spring Sem 2020
Fall Sem 2021
Spring Sem 2021
```

I want this output to be stored in an array.
i.e.

```
arr[0]="Fall Sem 2020"
```

My try: 
`arr=($(sed -En 's/.* lb="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file))`
But in this case, I'm getting individual element as an array element. i.e. 
`arr[0]="Fall"`

Comment: Check this thread --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628076/bash-convert-n-delimited-strings-into-array

Comment: The best answer in that Q&A is the last one using `readarray`, I'd say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(considering that OP doesn't have xml tools and can't install them too).

```
IFS=',';array=( $(
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="," }
/<subject lb="/{
  match($0,/".*"/)
  val=(val?val OFS:"")substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
}
END{
  print val
}' Input_file))
```

***To print all elements of array use:***

```
echo ${array[@]}
Fall Sem 2020 Spring Sem 2020 Fall Sem 2021 Spring Sem 2021
```

***To print specific element use:***

```
echo ${array[0]}
Fall Sem 2020
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
# disable job control and enable lastpipe to run mapfile in current environment
set +m; shopt -s lastpipe

sed -En 's/.* lb="([^"]+)".*/\1/p' file | mapfile -t arr

declare -p arr
```

Output:

```
declare -a arr=([0]="Fall Sem 2020" [1]="Spring Sem 2020" [2]="Fall Sem 2021" [3]="Spring Sem 2021")
```

In a script job control is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XML aware tool such as [XmlStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to extract the attribute you want, and then use [`readarray`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#index-readarray) and process substitution to read the output into an array:

```
$ readarray -t arr < <(xml sel -t -v 'classes/subject/@lb' infile.xml)
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="Fall Sem 2020" [1]="Spring Sem 2020" [2]="Fall Sem 2021" [3]="Spring Sem 2021")
```